# TypeError when creating a SHA512 hash using pyCryto

Tags: python-3.x, pycrypto

Evening All,

I am wanting to verify a a file using Public Key crypto and I cant figure out why I'm getting a Type error for the below code, note `signatureLength = 512`

```
signature = f[:signatureLength]
f = open('lib/publicKey.pem','rb')
publicKey = RSA.importKey(f.read())
hash = SHA512.new(f[signatureLength:])
verification = PKCS1_PSS.new(publicKey)
```

The specific error is:

```
  File "C:\Users\Zach Newton\Desktop\pp\lib\files.py", line 77, in verify_file
    hash = SHA512.new(f[signatureLength:])
TypeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reassigning the name `f`:

```
signature = f[:signatureLength]
f = open('lib/publicKey.pem','rb')
publicKey = RSA.importKey(f.read())
hash = SHA512.new(f[signatureLength:]) # <-- this isn't the same f anymore
verification = PKCS1_PSS.new(publicKey)
```

You should use something like this instead:

```
signature = f[:signatureLength]
with open('lib/publicKey.pem','rb') as pubkeyfile:
    publicKey = RSA.importKey(pubkeyfile.read())
hash = SHA512.new(signature)
verification = PKCS1_PSS.new(publicKey)
```

For that reason using generic variable names like `f` and reusing names for something completely different is discouraged.

Comment: Thanks Mata, much appreciated